# Is it possible during a Git Merge to out put any conflicts to log file?

Tags: git, git-merge

Doing some automation around merging a master branch into my working branch. I can easily automate the merge process and commit, but with the automation being headless and done on a schedule, is there anyway to get Git to output a file with the merge results if the merge failed due to conflicts? I plan to then email the output to a group of developers to then resolve the conflict.

Thanks in advance
Alex

Comment: What's wrong with detecting `git merge` failed (it returns a non-zero exit code) and then e-mailing the output of `git status [--porcelain]`? After that, your script could call `git merge --reset` to restore the work tree to the pre-merge state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure `git merge` will exit with non-0 status if it bailed out due to conflicts. And if you saved the output, there you have it.

Also after the command `git status` will show a clean state on success, while with conflicts it will list the unmerged paths. (you can use switches to just get the specific file lists and nothing else, so that must be easy to script.)